# Dependency Analysis Warning - XCODE 5

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

I Got This Error: 
OS X deployment target '10.9' for architecture 'x86_64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '10.8' for the OS X 10.8 SDK.

Here Is My Code:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  IMG Viewer
//
//  Created by Jeremy Irvine on 11/01/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jezza23 inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}

- (IBAction)OpenImage:(id)sender {
    NSOpenPanel *ImageOpener = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [ImageOpener runModal];
    NSURL *imagePath = [ImageOpener URL];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imagePath];

    [_ImageWindow setImage:image];
}
@end
```

And AppDelegate.h:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  IMG Viewer
//
//  Created by Jeremy Irvine on 11/01/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jezza23 inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *ImageWindow;
- (IBAction)OpenImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Check your build settings for that app target and make sure you're building for the proper OS version and compiling for an x86 cpu. Doesn't look like your code is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In your Xcode project, show the Build Settings for your target (by clicking on the Project in the Project navigator, then selecting the Target and clicking on the "Build Settings" tab). In the Build Setting search box, type "Deploy". It should show the deployment settings, one of which is named "OS X Deployment Target". That should be set to "OS X 10.8" (or lower) if you're building against the OS X 10.8 SDK.